# How to decode cmd = 3222823425 in ioctl in Linux 2.6.29?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am just confused like how can I break `cmd=3222823425` value into different parts to figure out what this command means actually in the Linux kernel. I know, some functions are making `ioctl` command with following parameters but I want to know what these parameter values mean.

```
fd=21, cmd=3222823425 and arg=3203118816
```

I have been looking into various forums, man pages and other links to figure this out like what does it mean when a `cmd` in an `ioctl` system call has value of `3222823425`. I have found that cmd is a command number which consists of `type`, `number` and `data_type` and first twos are `8-bit` integers (0-255).

So my question is how to decode these parameter values to find out what this call is trying to do?

Comment: If somebody wants more detailed answer to this question, [here][1] it is.


  [1]: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60620/how-to-decode-cmd-3222823425-in-ioctl-in-linux-2-6-29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [link](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-1), `ioctl` command number has multiple components:

- `type`. The magic number.This field is _IOC_TYPEBITS bits wide (usually 8)
- `number`. The ordinal (sequential) number. It's _IOC_NRBITS bits wide. (usually 8)
- `direction`. The direction of data transfer. The possible values are _IOC_NONE (no data transfer), _IOC_READ, _IOC_WRITE, and _IOC_READ|_IOC_WRITE (data is transferred both ways). It's usually 2 bits.
- `size`. The size of user data involved. It's _IOC_SIZEBITS wide (14 bits).

You should consult `include/asm/ioctl.h` and `Documentation/ioctl-number.txt` for your kernel to see the actual configuration.

For your case 3222823425==0xC0186201

So:

- `type`==0xC0
- `number`==0x18
- `direction`==0x1
- `size`==0x2201

(6 in bits is 0110, so the `size` is the first two bits(01), the remaining bits are put in `data_type`, which remains 0x2201)

Comment: thanks. I was just confused with the bits division among components and your answer was helpful. =)

Comment: You got the order of fields wrong. See [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18346951/1111371).

Answer (score 4):

Beware to refer to the right documentation to understand how to **decode** an ioctl command. `Documentation/ioctl-number.txt` explanes how to create a *new* ioctl code, while the document linked in the previous answer gives an overview of the overall process before focusing on ioctl creation as well. `asm/ioctl.h` is a better source, because an ioctl actual masking may vary across different architectures, but an explanation of the general convention and bitfields meaning and position can be found in `include/asm-generic/ioctl.h` and `Documentation/ioctl-decoding.txt`.

From the latter:

```
 bits     meaning
 31-30     00 - no parameters: uses _IO macro
           10 - read: _IOR
           01 - write: _IOW
           11 - read/write: _IOWR

 29-16  size of arguments

 15-8   ascii character supposedly
        unique to each driver

 7-0    function #
```

According to the above, cmd=3222823425 should decode as:


3222823425 -> 0xC0186201 -> 11000000000110000110001000000001

```
- `direction`   ->  `11`              ->  read/write;
- `size`        ->  `00000000011000`  ->  24 bytes (a pointer to a struct of
                                          this size should  be passed as 3rd
                                          argument of ioctl();
- `type`        ->  `01100010`        ->  0x62, ascii for character 'b';
- `number`      ->  `00000001`        ->  driver function #1.
```

In the hope this can help.
Regards.